# Trouble with the listing/ updating server parameters for azure postgres flexible server

Tags: postgresql, azure, azure-postgresql

The issue is observed on Azure Portal, CLI along with IaC Terraform provisioning.
[image]

Comment: Could you please add the additonal information about the expected result and the approach that you are following?

Comment: It has some sort of internal issue at azure end, which was resolved after a support case with MSFT, 
Support engineer described the issue as,
Backend PG team has checked that there is a duplicate folder in /datadrive so it it not understanding ones it is deleted from our end you can see the server parameters